# Regenerate as an adjective

Tags: grammar

Used as an adjective, when should the words regenerate vs. regenerative be employed?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want "adjectival" ***regenerate*** to mean, but most such usages are marked *rare* and/or *obsolete* in OED, so you'd want to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the dictionary is your friend:

> ***regenerate***: **v.** regrow to replace lost or injured tissue.  Bring into renewed existence.  Bring new and more vigorous life to, esp. in economic terms.  Give a new and higher spiritual nature to.  [New Oxford American Dictionary Third Edition]
>
> ***regenerate***: **adj.** precipitate in a different form following chemical processing, esp. in the form of fibers.  Reformed or reborn, esp. in a spiritual or moral sense. [New Oxford American Dictionary Third Edition]

With this definition in mind, you would use *regenerate* as a verb as follows:

> Once destroyed, brain cells do not regenerate. [New Oxford American Dictionary Third Edition]
>
> The issue was regenerated last month.  [New Oxford American Dictionary Third Edition]

And you would use *regenerate* as an adjective as follows:

> He is a regenerate Christian.
>
> The polymer is now a regenerate polymer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that outside of technical writing, "regenerate" is certain to be grokked early and often as the antonym of "degenerate". So, go ahead and use it, but with care.